# Jtest(cli) for eclipse is not finding any files, with "Source Files to Check: 0"

Tags: eclipse, parasoft

When I run tests using the Jtest within eclipse, source code files are checked and results are given.

but when I run this command line:

`jtestcli.exe -config "team://<our_team_conf>" -showdetails -localsettings "C:\<path_to_localsettings_file>\localsettings.properties" -data "C:\<path_to_workspace>\workspace\<project_name>" -report "C:\<path_to_report>\report" -publish`

1. Why are ZERO source code files checked?
2. How does `jtestcli` find its source files?

.

```
****Total Files: 0
Source Files to Check: 0
Total Source Lines: --
Source Lines to Check: --
Test Data Files: ---
Excluded Files: 0****


**
**Files Checked (Coding Standards): 0/0
Files Skipped (Coding Standards): 0
Files Checked (BugDetective): 0/0
Files Skipped (BugDetective): 0
Projects - Metrics Estimated: 0/0 - 0/0
Failed Runs: 0
Violations Found: 0
Violations Suppressed: 0
Number of Rules Violated: 0**



****Executed Test Cases: 0
Passed:  --     Failed: --     Skipped: --
Runtime Exceptions: 0
Assertion Failures: 0
Contract Violations: 0
Runtime Error Detection Violations: 0
Unverified Outcomes: 0
Coverage:
   Line: --
   Decision: --
Runtime Error Detection:
   Classes Loaded: --  Analyzed: --  Instrumented: --
   Number of Rules Violated: 0
   Violations Suppressed: 0**
**

result:
-Empty PDF reports
-No result uploaded to concerto
```

Answer (score 0):

With -data option you specify path to the workspace, so in order to test project <project_name> inside C:\<path_to_workspace>\workspace, you should use:

```
   -data "C:\<path_to_workspace>\workspace" -resource "<project_name>"
```

rather than:

```
   -data "C:\<path_to_workspace>\workspace\<project_name>"
```